# What Determines if a Drug appears on OpenFDA or Not?

Tags: openfda

I'm attempting to use OpenFDA to query a drug's package NDC and return information like manufacturer, brand name, and route.

I have the following query working, but noticed (during testing) I get no results for the 3rd below (Botox).  Is Botox intentionally omitted?  Am I doing something incorrect.  If I remove the exact match, and search, I do get results, but none appear to be for Botox (it finds other partial matches on the manufacturer segment of the NDC, etc.)

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc.exact:62332-464-31

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc.exact:0378-9320-32

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=openfda.package_ndc.exact:0023-1145-01

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenFDA section is optional and is not guaranteed to be present for each drug label. 
In this case, there was some sort of matching error in the harmonization process, so no harmonized data was provided for that particular set_id.

https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=set_id:485d9b71-6881-42c5-a620-a4360c7192ab

we'll investigate further when we have new SPL data so that we can see what exactly is causing this matching error.
About the drug labeling overview please check here.
https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/label/